# enough electrical knowledge to get me in trouble

Tags: neutral

I have an Arc welder and just picked up a spot welder.  Checking the Arc welder cord I found it has 4 wires.  The green is cut off and the white is used.  Do I need to have the neutral (white) and the ground hooked up also?  The arc welder has worked but it does blow my duel 60 Amp breaker sometimes.  Is that because the Green ground line is not hooked up? the white and green go to the same location.

Comment: The arc welder was given to me.  I put in a 30 amp fuse box.  Its the kind with two screw in 30b amp fuses.  The white and ground go to the ground bar.

Comment: What make, model, and namplate specifications are on this welder?

Comment: Also, you have a 4-wire feed running to where you are plugging this welder in, right?